# Convert image to base 64 without store in any folder

Tags: laravel, image, base64

Is it possible to direct convert from $request->image to base64 format? I dont want to save in any folder. But seem only photo in folder are able to convert to base64. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think, You should try below code.

`$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('image')->pat‌​h()));`

Laravel's $request->file() doesn't return the actual file content so, it returns an instance of the upload file class.

Hence, You need to load the actual file to be able to convert it